# JMS is unable to lookup Queue

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

I installed Glassfish5 and started it using eclipse. I also logged to the Glassfish admin console and created two queues namely Queue01 and Queue02 under the JMS Resources\Destination Resources option. The code doesn't but when I run it, the last thing it performs is the print statement before the lookup command. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Main implements MessageListener{


public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException,NamingException, IOException{

    if(args.length!=3) System.out.println("usage: username subscribe-to-queue publish-to-queue");
    else {
        String username = args[0];
        System.out.println("username: " + username + " | subscribe-to-queue-name " + args[1] + " | publish-to-queue-name " + args[2]);
        Context initialContext = Main.getInitialContext();
        Main myMain = new Main();
        System.out.println("Before Queue");
        Queue queue01 = (Queue) initialContext.lookup(args[1]);
        Queue queue02 = (Queue) initialContext.lookup(args[2]);
        //java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory is the default conection at the JMS app server (no need to define it)
        System.out.println("Before ConnectionFactory");
        JMSContext jmsContext = ((ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")).createContext();
        //we use jms context to pickup jms consumer and assign it our own class (Main)
        System.out.println("Before createConsumer");
        jmsContext.createConsumer(queue01).setMessageListener(myMain);
        System.out.println("Before jmsProducer");
        JMSProducer jmsProducer = jmsContext.createProducer();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String msgToSend = null;

        System.out.println("Before while");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter msg:");
            msgToSend = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if(msgToSend.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                jmsContext.close();
                System.exit(0);
            }else {
                System.out.println("Before send");
                jmsProducer.send(queue02, "["+username+": "+msgToSend+"]");
                System.out.println("after send");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try{System.out.println(message.getBody(String.class));}
    catch (JMSException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static Context getInitialContext () throws JMSException,NamingException
{
     Properties prop = new Properties();
     prop.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
     prop.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jnp.interfaces");
     prop.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:3700");
     Context context = new InitialContext(prop);


    //Context context = new InitialContext();

return context;
}

}
```

Any hint one what is wrong with my code that leads to not being able to execute the lookup command? The problem is that I'm not seeing any error messages to give me a hint on what is wrong. I tried changing the provider url without a luck.

Comment: How are you running the application? Are you sure you'd see any error output from the JVM related to an exception which was thrown? Also, can you paste the output?

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm using Eclipse oxygen. First, I start the glassfish server from inside eclipse using the server view. Then, I run the application from Eclipse by right-clicking the java file -> run as java app. I add the command line arguments by updating the Arguments tab inside the run configurations. The code executes and the last things it does is to print "Before queue".

Comment: I would surround everything in `main` with a `try/catch` block and call `printStackTrace(System.out)` on any exception so that you can ensure you'll see any exceptions. Another option would just be to step through the code using your debugger to see what's actually happening. Since you're already running this from your IDE it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: I used try catch that catches any exception, but, the code fires no exceptions. It gets stuck at the lookup command (initialContext.lookup(args[1])). The way I'm setting up the context properties (provider.url) may be the problem. As Im trying to connect to a local Queue created in the GF server running on same machine where I run my code, does it make sense to have the provider url as "jnp://localhost:3700". The GF console lists port 3700 under iiop. But, when I change jnp in the url to iiop, I receive the error: (Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: iiop://localhost:3700)

Comment: This error is not fired when I use jnp in the url.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think Glassfish uses JNP for JNDI. I believe that's what the JBoss application server uses. Keep in mind that JNDI implementations differ from server to server so you can't necessarily use the same properties for one as you do with another. The fact that it's getting stuck indicates you're using the wrong properties.